# Is there any best reader in all devices?

Tags: ebook-readers, pdf, epub-reader

I have been using readera, xodo & kindle in my mobile for reading epub, mobi. Usually I read pdfs through default pdf Acrobat in the mobile. Also I'm using Ms edge for pdf, ice cream for epub ebooks in the windows machine.

But I want to know a reader which should like Kindle app which mean the platform free. It can be used in both mobile and desktop. Also need a cloud backup for that. Is there any e-reader application existing with my requirements?

Comment: Short answer: probably not. I am not an expert, but the basic idea is that for-profit businesses set themselves aside from the crowd by implementing all kinds of proprietary details (file formats, features, services...). So you can go ahead with something open source, they tend to support mostly everything - possibly except DRM protected files. Usually, PDF is not friendly at all with physical readers (i.e., the dedicated devices, usually with e-ink screens) - simply because it is not reflow-able.